# firefox 18.0.1 CSS messed on some client-end.

Tags: css, firefox

Why is it on some end, the CSS messes.. it works great on some other versions and different browsers.

I have tested it on 2 different laptops. This is how it looks on their computer. 
[image]

While it works great on my end.. both test are running on windows.. 
[image]

here is the live link if you want to see it live http://goo.gl/fPJTe

Comment: You are doing something wrong. There can be many reasons. No, we won't decompose the link you've given (and which will change soon). And no, screenshots are not really helpful. Also keep in mind that you should ask questions here that are useful for others as well. When you have fixed your CSS issue, the question here is not of use for anybody else in the current form. Make it eternal instead.

Comment: I have asked because I ran out of solution to think. I have tested it on http://browsershots.org/ and on the browserlab on adobe. My friend also tested it on his laptop with clean install, no plugins added with that particular version. It's not yet useful because no one has ever yet face this kind of problem because as I have said the firefox version I am asking is new and their is newer release though.

Comment: Which Firefox version is their computer using? Do you have access to their computer? Or only a screenshot? What did you try so far? (the screenshot you have looks like a partial download. if their computer has connection problems to the internet there is not much you can do. Try with putting everything into a zip-file and make them open the page from their own harddisk to move the network as trouble-driver out of the way)

Comment: As the title says, its' firefox 18.0.1... I don't have access but I have tested it on different computers but have the same result. Running on Windows with that firefox version.

Comment: Looks like that somebody fooled you with a broken screenshot. We do these jokes often so the frontend devs learn a lesson.

Comment: @hakre, you are just here to troll around. I'm not fooling you here. This problem exist on my employer's end and also my Project manager test it on his machine and got the same result.

Comment: I don't fool you, I just wrote what *could* be the case. You should instead try to reproduce it on your end before fixing it otherwise it will take ages (considering how long it already took).

Comment: I can't see it on my machine so I can't directly test it. I can't even figure out how to reproduce the error. My friend had it on a clean install and he can see the messed version while I'm not though I also did the same.

Comment: Yeah, those esoteric errors are hard to catch. Normally it helps when you sleep one night over them.

Comment: @Ark helped a lot with this.. and we solved it. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

#ja-banner div { display: inline-block; }

in your css

worked here

EDIT:

changed to div working on ff 18

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work here for me. Can you paste the whole CSS file?

Comment: Please move the mouse over the downvote button, it gives a description that should explain it in form of a tooltip.

Comment: whats wrong in trying to help someone? just because you didnt wanted doesnt mean i dont want too, troll somewhere else

Comment: Actually I hope nothing is wrong in helping someone. At least it should not, so why do you have a problem with my comment that was intended to help you? You had a question, I answered it and now you call me a troll? This does not work out well.

Comment: my comment has been removed.

Comment: hakre you're not helping :(

@Ark, Have you tried it on same version?..

Comment: @Ark, same result. I have ask my friend and updated the codes. have you try it on the same version?

Comment: @MarkBean yep 18.0.1 just checked, he is inserting on the css file?

Comment: @Ark
I have added it on myself on the CSS file and then check it on his end. same result, nothing chaned.

Comment: @MarkBean use #ja-banner:first-child { display: inline-block !important; } then

Comment: ok, added it with !important.. still the same @Ark

Comment: have you tried the messed version? because I can't see it on my machine so I can't directly test it. I can't even figure out how to reproduce the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24047/discussion-between-mark-bean-and-ark)